# How to apply styles to a div element by clicking on its children (angular2/ts)

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

HTML

```
<div class="tableRow">
  <div id="0-0">
    <p>Point {{levelOne}}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="0-1" (click)="select($event)">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-2" (click)="select($event)">
    <li >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-3" (click)="select($event)">
    <li>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-4" (click)="select($event)">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-5" (click)="select($event)">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tableRow {
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 18% 18% 18% 18% 18%;
}

.tableRow > div {
  background: $white;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid $purple-70;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tableRow > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: $purple-10;
  cursor: default;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

TS

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

    @Component({
      selector: "example",
      templateUrl: "./example.component.html"
    })
    export class Example implements OnInit {

      public levelOne: Number = 1;
      public levelTwo: Number = 3;
      public levelThree: Number = 9;
      public LevelFour: Number = 27;

      public selected = false;

      constructor() {}

      ngOnInit() {}


    select($event) {
      let id = $event.target.id;
      if ($event.target.localName !== "div") {
        let id = $event.target.parentElement.id;
      }
    console.log(id);
   }

  }
```

with the following code clicking outside the li element results in id being set to the actual id but when I click on the li element within the div id is set to undefined... however if i log *$event.target.parentElement.id* to the console it will print the correct ID when clicking the li element.

Im pretty sure If i can get the correct ID captured on click I can use that to assign a style (change background color of the div for example)

Im not sure what I am doing wrong, or is there a better way in general?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's bad practice (for too many reasons to list here) to access the dom directly when using angular. You can do pretty much anything with tools provided by Angular, element property bindings for example:

```
<div [class.selected]="div1Selected" (click)="div1Selected = !div1Selected">
    Has class `selected` when component's property `div1Selected` is true.
</div>
```

Comment: Is simply reading the ID of a MouseEvent target 'accessing the DOM directly'? Angular and TypeScript natively support MouseEvent objects. You can even typecast them accordingly.    select($event : MouseEvent) and then TypeScript intellisense will show you precisely what properties / methods are available on that event

Comment: Yes. It's not "the angular way" to depend on element id's.. By doing that you're missing a lot of the real power in Angular and would be best to learn how to achieve things without resorting to that.

Comment: I generally understand the reasons for not reading native DOM properties, but in what alternative environment would it be problematic to read ID's? Could you not just check if the target is an HTMLElement and if it has an ID, and if it does, use that? If it doesn't, resort to some other targeting method? I'm sincerely curious bc I occasionally use this method in my own code as an alternative to creating potentially thousands of individual event listeners or distinct components inside ngFor loops. I programatically bind the id's to something unique with id="{{whatever}}" and then target w that

Comment: In a *ngFor loop, you could just pass the current item to the function, eg. *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="clicked(item)"

Comment: and the let's say you want to change the clicked item's style, just toggle some flag in the item eg. item.selected=!item.selected and then you can bind that to a style class

Comment: But then that creates an individual event listener for each element generated by the for loop, right? That's what I was trying to avoid. It becomes problematic if I'm, say, using a for loop to generate thousands of rows on a spreadsheet. I always assumed the one off binding of the ID was more performant than individual, always-on listeners

Comment: Yes but it's not a perf biggie. You could have tens of thousands of elements with a (click) binding before it becomes a strain. And rendering the dom is probably more stress on it's own. In such case pagination or virtual scrolling is needed anyway

Comment: But yeah, it's totally ok in my mind to use a general click listener for the whole table too in some cases ie if you don't want any pagination :)

Comment: check this awesome virtual scroll lib btw. Really performant when you only render the elements that fit the viewport and reuse elements :) https://github.com/aminpaks/angular-virtual-list

Comment: Interesting... I think I need to do some tests between binding thousands of IDs vs. creating thousands of listeners. I always assumed one was much more efficient than the other but honestly never tested it. That's really the only use case where I depend on ID's. if it doesn't make a big difference I'm gonna refactor my code! thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a style binding to bind whatever style you want to the parent div, and then use the child div clicks to change the value of the string bound to that style.

```
<div class="tableRow" [style.background]="myStyle">
  <div id="0-0">
    <p>Point {{levelOne}}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="0-1" (click)="myStyle = 'red'">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-2" (click)="myStyle = 'blue'">
    <li >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod. </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-3" (click)="myStyle = 'green'">
    <li>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-4" (click)="myStyle = 'orange'">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  </div>
  <div id="0-5" (click)="myStyle = 'magenta'">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "example",
  templateUrl: "./example.component.html"
})
export class Example implements OnInit {

  public levelOne: Number = 1;
  public levelTwo: Number = 3;
  public levelThree: Number = 9;
  public LevelFour: Number = 27;

  myStyle = 'inherit';

  public selected = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to reduce the number of event listeners you are adding to your page, you could just set a single event listener on the parent div, and use the $event.target id's to check the target child div, and set the string based on that target.

```
  <div class="tableRow" [style.background]="myStyle" (click)="setStyle($event)">
```

Then just add a func in your component similar to what you already have

```
select($event) {
  let id = ($event.target as HTMLElement).id;
  // here you could add a a switch case that sets the myStyle string based on the id of the clicked element
```